# Logstash rename a particular field?

Tags: logstash

I have slow logs like this...

```
[2017-01-13 14:37:48,943][DEBUG][index.search.slowlog.query] [Spectra] [test][4] took[50micros], took_millis[0], types[], stats[], search_type[QUERY_THEN_FETCH], total_shards[5], source[], extra_source[], 
[2017-01-13 12:58:09,844][WARN ][index.search.slowlog.query] [Spectra] [testindex-stats][1] took[16.2ms], took_millis[16], types[], stats[], search_type[QUERY_THEN_FETCH],
```

I need to rename took[50micros] to took[50ms] in all the slowlogs . How can i able to achieve this using logstash ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked fine with gsub filter

```
 mutate {
     gsub => [

      "TOOK", "micros", "ms"
    ]
}
```